# Download with PHP readfile() works in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, http-headers, output-buffering

I am having a problem with my webpage. I am building a report tool for downloading data as .csv - I have a php skript which aggregates the data and builds a csv from it. The skript is invoked with the `exec()` command, detailed code is below. The skript itself uses `file_put_contents()` to generate the file, which is then stored in my /tmp/ folder until its downloaded (I am working in a dockerized environment and our filter rules delete the file at the next request, but I could store the file permanently somewhere else if that would be neccessary). I am then checking if the file is present with `file_exists()` and proceed to invoke my download function. In Firefox I get the desired result, a file with the correct content of only the csv data.

**My main Problem is:** When I download the csv in Chrome I get the csv data followed by the html source of my page - so starting with `<!doctype html>` in the first line after the csv data, then `<html lang="de">`in the next line of te csv and so on..

Let me show you some code:

In my skript:

```
private function writeToFile($csv)
{
    $fileName = '/path/to/file' '.csv';
    echo "\n" . 'Write file to ' . $fileName . "\n";
    file_put_contents($fileName, $csv);
}
```

In my page class:

```
    $filePath = '/path/to/finished/csv/'
    exec('php ' . $skriptPath . $skriptParams);
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        $this->downloadCsv($filePath);
    } else {
        $pageModel->addMessage(
            new ErrorMessage('Error Text')
        );
    }
```

My download function in the same class:

```
private function downloadCsv($filePath)
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
    readfile($filePath);
}
```

***The shown above is working in Firefox, but not in Chrome.*** I already tried to clear the output buffer with `ob_clean()` or send and disable it with `ob_end_flush()` but nothing worked for Chrome.

I also tried something like this in my download function:

```
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');

    $fp =fopen($filePath, 'rw');
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
```

This produces the same results in Firefox and Chrome - I get the csv data followed by the html sourcecode mixed into the same file.

I am working within a Symfony framework if that could be from help, I saw there are some helper functions for file downloads but I so far I could not use them with success..

Until now my target is only to get the download working in Chrome to have a working mvp which can go into production - it is supposed to be for internal use only, so I don't have to care about IE or some other abominations because our staff is told to use a normal browser... But when someone sees flaws in the general concept feel free to tell me!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it working, I was on the wrong track with the output buffer, but a simple `exit()`after my `readfile()`was enough to stop parts of the html ending up in the csv file.

Code:

```
private function downloadCsv($filePath)
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filePath));
    readfile($filePath);
    exit;

}
```